# Android R.java Syntax error on token "int", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Tags: android, syntax-error, r.java-file

I am getting the following constantly generating in the R.java file:

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int   =0x7f0500ae;
```

I have done research and it all pointing to the strings file. I have checked my strings file and there is no errors. The application is not producing errors anywhere else, its just this single line that is being generated.

Can someone please help.

Comment: R file is auto generated, you dont need to look into it. cause or error will either be in java or xml files

Comment: Yes I know its auto generated, my question was why is it telling me there is an error and generating a blank int, when my application is stating there is no error else where

Comment: I'm sure I am not along in saying I have absolutely no idea what your problem is nor what question you are asking.

Comment: I would guess you named some id resource wrong. Perhaps using national characters or a leading digit, or there might be a typo in the XML markup "@+id/...". The line is supposed to read `public static final int name = 0x...`, where "name" is what you put into the XML.

Comment: Thank you Vašek Potoček, that answer was correct, in one of my xml layout files the id of an item had messed up and was not labeled correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue and found it odd that my strings.xml file didn't show any errors, but was able to resolve by searching through the strings.xml file for empty string name values.

Found:

```
<string name="">Username</string>
```

Changed to:

```
<string name="lblUsername">Username</string>
```

Worked and was able to compile, hope this helps.

Comment: This is correct, I managed to solve the problem a while ago but forgot to mark this question as answered. The problem for me was similar to this, mine was in my xml file and the xml file wasn't showing an error.

Answer (score 0):

One or more xml files might have compilation problem. Can you check?
If you are using eclipse, sometimes the xml file or folder wont show it has error (red * icon in the file or folder.

If this is not the case then delete the R.java file and rebuild the project. 
or
Clean your project and rebuild it again.